# Updating Angular 8 to Angular 9 unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been trying to update our Angular 8 to 9 except I keep running into an error about dependencies not being able to be resolved.

I tried updating the local CLI first but that gave me the same errors. My global CLI is updated as well. Running `ng update @angular/cli@9` gives me the following error:

```
    Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.29
node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
  dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.901.13" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.901.13" from the root project

Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@9.1.13
node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
  peer @angular/compiler-cli@">=9.0.0 < 10" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.13
  node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
    dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.901.13" from the root project
```

Following the Angular update tool doesn't seem of much help. How do I go about fixing this error?

Comment: Does running `npm update` before running `ng update` help?

Comment: This gives me a resolve error as well, but "jasmine-core" this time.

Comment: https://update.angular.io/?v=8.0-9.0 This should help you. E.g. it shows, that you need to update `cli` alongside `core` in one command.

Comment: I've done this, results in the same dependency error

Comment: `Devkit` seems to not update correctly (still 0.803.29). Try updating that to 0.901.13.

Comment: I tried running `ng update @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.13` but it gives the same error. Using npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.13 gives an error that the CLI needs a lower version

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what causes the issue but running the exact same steps on a different machine solved it. Both machines run the same versions of node/npm/angular CLI etc. Cannot tell what the issue was.